# NetBeans has no Java option

Tags: java, netbeans

So I went to the Oracle site, [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html), and downloaded the JDK and NetBeans bundle file.  Followed the download instructions, and ran it.  It opens up and seems to run fine, but when I try to create a file, it asks which file type.  Java isn't any of the options: There is only XML and Other.  Under Other, the closest I see is Java Script with I know is not the same thing as Java.  I also ran the JDK file and tried again, but still Java isn't an option in NetBeans.

Help?

Comment: have you checked out their [quick start guide](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/quickstart.html) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create a java file you first need to create a java project.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here exists when you are sitting at the NetBeans home screen and click on 'New File' instead of 'New Project'.

When you click on 'New File', it only gives you the 'Other' and 'XML' options. When you click on 'New Project', you get all the options you would expect, including Java.

The 'New File' icon is the white page with the green '+' sign. 
The new project button is next to that, with a tan square and a green '+' sign.